# Set background-image of <div> in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, getjson

I am trying to set the `background-image` property of a `<div>` in Javascript, but the image won't appear. The height is 100px, and I can see that the content beneath it is pushed down, but here is no image.

Here is my code:

```
var bg = document.createElement("div");

$.getJSON("https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/profile?kaid=kaid_783146703471696540623752&callback=?", function(data) {
    bg.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Basilica_of_Saint_Achilles%2C_Florina%2C_Greece.jpg/1280px-Basilica_of_Saint_Achilles%2C_Florina%2C_Greece.jpg");';
    bg.style.height = "100px";
    statsDiv.appendChild(bg);
    //some other stuff that uses the JSON that doesn't matter
});
```

I know that the `<div>` is *there*, because It shows the 100px gap in between the elements, but no image, and the `$.getJSON()` works.

***Solution:***

I just had to remove the semicolon:

Before:
`bg.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Basilica_of_Saint_Achilles%2C_Florina%2C_Greece.jpg/1280px-Basilica_of_Saint_Achilles%2C_Florina%2C_Greece.jpg");';`

After:
`bg.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Basilica_of_Saint_Achilles%2C_Florina%2C_Greece.jpg/1280px-Basilica_of_Saint_Achilles%2C_Florina%2C_Greece.jpg")';`

Comment: `.jpg");'` <-- remove the semicolon. You do not add the `;` in the rule when setting it with JavaScript.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Looks good so far. The new div has to be appended to the DOM.

```js
$.getJSON("https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/profile?kaid=kaid_783146703471696540623752&callback=?", function() {
    console.log("success");

    var bg = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(bg);
    bg.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Basilica_of_Saint_Achilles%2C_Florina%2C_Greece.jpg/1280px-Basilica_of_Saint_Achilles%2C_Florina%2C_Greece.jpg')";

    bg.style.height = "100px";

  })
  .done(function() {
    console.log("second success");
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
  });
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

This works for me:

```js
const statsDiv = $('.statsDiv');

statsDiv.append('<div class="bgdiv"></div>');
const bg = $(".bgdiv");

const bgimageURL = 'url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Basilica_of_Saint_Achilles%2C_Florina%2C_Greece.jpg/1280px-Basilica_of_Saint_Achilles%2C_Florina%2C_Greece.jpg")';

$.getJSON("https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/profile?kaid=kaid_783146703471696540623752&callback=?", function(data) {
    bg.css({
      'background-image': bgimageURL,
      'height': '100px'
    });
    statsDiv.append(bg);
    
    // ...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="statsDiv">This is statsDiv</div>
```

(Edit: my original answer was incorrect. I fixed it)